# Type for representing a list with 0 to 5 values

Tags: haskell

I have an exercise where I have to define a type for representing a list with 0 to 5 values. First I thought I could solve this recursively like this:

```
data List a = Nil | Content a (List a)
```

But I don't think this is the correct approach. Can you please give me a food of thought.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I won’t answer your exercise for you — for exercises, it’s better to figure out the answer yourself — but here’s a hint which should lead you to the answer: you can define a list with 0 to 2 elements as

```
data List a = None | One a | Two a a
```

Now, think about how can you extend this to five elements.

Answer (score 14):

Well, a recursive solution is certainly the normal and in fact *nice* thing in Haskell, but it's a bit tricky to limit the number of elements then. So, for a *simple solution* to the problem, first consider the stupid-but-working one given by bradm.

With the recursive solution, the trick is to pass a “counter” variable down the recursion, and then disable consing more elements when you reach the max allowed. This can be done nicely with a GADT:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeInType, StandaloneDeriving #-}

import Data.Kind
import GHC.TypeLits

infixr 5 :#
data ListMax :: Nat -> Type -> Type where
  Nil :: ListMax n a
  (:#) :: a -> ListMax n a -> ListMax (n+1) a

deriving instance (Show a) => Show (ListMax n a)
```

Then

```
*Main> 0:#1:#2:#Nil :: ListMax 5 Int
0 :# (1 :# (2 :# Nil))

*Main> 0:#1:#2:#3:#4:#5:#6:#Nil :: ListMax 5 Int

<interactive>:13:16: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘1’ with ‘0’
      Expected type: ListMax 0 Int
        Actual type: ListMax (0 + 1) Int
    • In the second argument of ‘(:#)’, namely ‘5 :# 6 :# Nil’
      In the second argument of ‘(:#)’, namely ‘4 :# 5 :# 6 :# Nil’
      In the second argument of ‘(:#)’, namely ‘3 :# 4 :# 5 :# 6 :# Nil’
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Because it's a beginner exercise I think it's the easier approach. But I will think about your approach too.

Answer (score 8):

For the sake of completeness, let me add an "ugly" alternative approach, which is however rather basic.

Recall that `Maybe a` is a type whose values are of the form `Nothing` or `Just x` for some `x :: a`.

Hence, by reinterpreting the values above, we can regard `Maybe a` as a "restricted list type" where lists can have either zero or one element.

Now, `(a, Maybe a)` simply adds one more element, so it is a "list type" where lists can have one (`(x1, Nothing)`) or two (`(x1, Just x2)`) elements.

Therefore, `Maybe (a, Maybe a)` is a "list type" where lists can have zero (`Nothing`), one (`Just (x1, Nothing)`), or two (`(Just (x1, Just x2)`) elements.

You should now be able to understand how to proceed. Let me stress again that this is not a convenient solution to use, but it is (IMO) a nice exercise to understand it anyway.

---

Using some advanced features of Haskell, we can generalize the above using a type family:

```
type family List (n :: Nat) (a :: Type) :: Type where
    List 0 a = ()
    List n a = Maybe (a, List (n-1) a)
```

Comment: This answer could be extended with the type family of Maybe-based list of max-length _n_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Done. That might be a bit too much for a beginner, but I added it anyway.

Comment: at most three `a`s in `Either () (a, Either () (a, Either () (a, Either () ())))`... interesting type algebra, `foldr (.) id (replicate 3 $ ([0] ++) . liftA2 (+) [1]) $ [0] == [0,1,2,3]`.